# How to solve this without using a long boolean expression?

Tags: java

```
package pks;

    public class pks {
        public static void main (String args[])

        {
        System.out.println (isDaphne(new int[]{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 6}));
        }

        static int isDaphne (int [ ] a) {
        int counter=0;
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)

        {
            if (a[i] == 0 && a[i+1] == 0 && a[i+2] + a[i+3] == 0) {

                counter++;
                break;

            }
            else     
            {

            }
        }
    return counter;
    }
}
```

Now the Output of the Program is 1 when there are 4 consecutive 0's

But I don't want use this expression:

```
if (a[i] == 0 && a[i+1] == 0 && a[i+2] + a[i+3] == 0)
```

Is there any other way to do this, without using the above expression?

Usage of additional array, hashmap etc. not allowed. Arrays.sort(..) not allowed

Comment: What is the *goal* of the program? If the goal is to test if the array contains 4 consecutive zeros, why don't you test that, instead of summing the 3rd and 4rth elements? What if the array contain 0, 0, -1, 1?

Comment: Can you use `while` ?

Comment: Goal of the problem is that if there are 4 consecutive 0's in the array then it should return 1 without using the above expression

Comment: Then your code is wrong. Use `a[i] == 0 && a[i+1] == 0 && a[i+2] == 0 && a[i+3] == 0` instead.

Comment: It works fine But this kind of expression is not allowed

Comment: Please define rules for what is allowed and what not.

Comment: Sir only this kind of Expression is not allowed in the code a[i] == 0 && a[i+1] == 0 && a[i+2] == 0 && a[i+3] == 0

Comment: So what can we change? What are our options? JBNizet showed in his comment version which changed `a[i+2] + a[i+3] == 0` into `a[i+2] == 0 && a[i+3] == 0` but it seems that this is not allowed. To be honest it is quite confusing.

Comment: @user3370649: if that's the only expression allowed, you got your answer (which is also mine).

Comment: Sir as I clearly mention that a[i] == 0 && a[i+1] == 0 && a[i+2] == 0 && a[i+3] == 0 this kind of expression is not permitted in this code...

Comment: @user3370649: You got another answer, using another expression, by usmcs, and you also commented that his expression wasn't allowed. Your question is not clear at all. Voted to close.

Comment: @user3370649 But you did not specify why? This is not any `additional array` or `hashmap` or similar, which are not allowed. I am asking then what is allowed.

Comment: I specify everything in my program I don't know why all are using the same Expression again and again.....

Comment: Your "specification" only says: `is there any other way to do this? without using the Above expression I don't want to use If statement`. As I asked earlier (now that comment is removed) is your goal removing `if` statement entirely or just changing it?

Comment: Because they're not the same expressions `a + b == 0` is not the same expression as `a == 0 && b == 0`, which is not the same expression as `a == b == 0 ? 1 : 0`. Look at them: the characters are not the same. So they're not the same expressions. You've been asked several times to tell us what is allowed, and didn't tell us.

Comment: My last try: is this expression allowed `if ((a[i] | a[i + 1] | a[i + 2] | a[i + 3]) == 0)`? If not, why (specific reason please)? I am starting to suspect that you don't want to get rid of `if` but `for` loop.

Comment: Is your return type correct for isDaphne? Do you intend it to be a boolean, rather than an int?

Comment: Sorry for all that I got my solution by the way thank u all

Comment: Go through the array; when you see a 0 start counting them. If you get 4, complain (or whatever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to check that input array of int contains four consecutive zeros.

I have two solution of that problem.

First:

```
int consecutiveZeros = 0;

for(int i=0; i< input.length; i++) {
  if(input[i] == 0) {
    consecutiveZeros++;
  } else {
    consecutiveZeros = 0;
  }

  if(consecutiveZeros == 4) {
    return true; 
  }
}
```

Second:

If the values in array are between 0 and 65 535. I would use type `char` instead of `int`.

```
static boolean isDaphne (char [] input) {
   return new String(input).contains("0000");
}
```

If you can not change the type of input. Write a wrapper that will change it, from int to char and use first solution.

Comment: Thank you so much I think this solution is Best for me sorry for not asking the question specifically.............

Comment: You can close the topic. By marking the answer as correct to your needs. Please also write witch solution fits your expectation.

Comment: A good improvement is to make bigger steps.. if the first one is not 0 then jump 4, it's like [string search algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)

Comment: This is not always true. In case you have input `100001111` your solution will not find the match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[LENGTH];
//fill array
Arrays.asList(array).subList(0,4).contains(0);// use i and i+4 in a for loop
```

And if you are looking for better time complexity this is a kind of string search. Take a look of [string searching algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)

Comment: Not necessarily correct. The third element of the `if` is a sum. The elements could contain `6` and `-6` and satisfy the condition.

Comment: This tests if one of the 4 first elements is 0. It doesn't do what the original code does.

Comment: @JBNizet is what he want i think, now reading the comments!

Comment: @AntonH is what he want i think 4 consecutive 0

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
static int isDaphne (int [ ] a) 
{
    int counter=0;
    int auxCounter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == 0)
        {
            ++auxCounter;
        }
        else
        {
            auxCounter = 0;
        }
        if(auxCounter > 3)
        {
           ++counter;
        }
    }
return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll give it a try:

Why not employ regular expression:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,0,0,0,0,4};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            //below will return true
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(".*0, 0, 0, 0.*",Arrays.toString(arr)));
    }
}
```

Is this allowed?